# percentages and CSS margins

Tags: css, margin

I have create a jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem:

> http://jsfiddle.net/MXt8d/1/

```
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 25%;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The thing is that when i need to horizontally center a div inside another.
I specify the height of the inner div in % (eg. 50%) and then the margin-top and margin-bottom to the remaining (eg. (100 - 50) / 2 = 25 %).

But as you see in the jsFiddle it's not working as intended.

Calculating the margins from the Parent works, but it's not possible for me, because I dont have access to the div's parent, as the elements-style object is bound to the object via knockout.js and it's not so simple as shown in the jsFiddle.

Hope anyone could help me :-)

bj99

**Update:**

Just found out why this is actually happening, so I'll post here for peaple with similar problems:

> From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top :
>
> 'margin-top', 'margin-bottom'
> Percentages:   refer to ***width*** of containing block

And not as I tought to the **height** :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `#inner` element:

1) Add `position:absolute`

2) Remove `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties

3) Add `top:25%`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

It is a solution to your problem.I hope I helped you

```
.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions to your problem:

1) add `position:absolute` and `top:25%` on the inner element - **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MXt8d/3/)**

2) use `display:table` on the outer and `display:table-cell` on the inner element, this also allows vertical centering.  - **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MXt8d/2/)**

Each of the solutions has some caveats, I personally try to avoid absolute positionings wherever I can, but this is also up to personal preferences.

Comment: Thanks alot, the absolute positioning is there fore the only way, because i cant change the html to add a wrapper :-/